# There is a text file want to return content of file in json format on the matching column

Tags: flask

there is a text file containing data in the form:

[sec1]
"ab": "s"
"sd" : "d"

[sec2]
"rt" : "ty"
"gh" : "rr"
"kk":"op"

we are supposed to return dara of matching sections in json format like if user wants sec1 so  we are supposed to send sec1 contents

Answer (score 0):

The format you specified is very similar to the TOML format. However, this one uses equals signs for assignments of key-value pairs.

If your format actually uses colons for the assignment, the following example may help you.
It uses [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) in conjunction with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to read the data from the file. The section to be queried is extracted from the URL using a [variable rule](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#variable-rules).
If there is no hit within the loaded data, the server responds with a 404 error (NOT FOUND).

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from flask import (
    Flask,
    abort,
    jsonify
)

def parse(f):
    data = defaultdict(dict)
    section = None
    for line in f:
        if re.match(r'^\[[^\]]+\]$', line.strip()):
            section = line[1:-2]
            data[section] = dict()
            continue
        m = re.match(r'^"(?P<key>[^"]+)"\s*:\s*"(?P<val>[^"]+)"$', line.strip())
        if m:
            key,val = m.groups()
            if not section:
                raise OSError('illegal format')
            data[section][key] = val
            continue
    return dict(data)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<string:section>')
def data(section):
    path = 'path/to/file'
    with open(path) as f:
        data = parse(f)
    if section in data:
        return jsonify(data[section])
    abort(404)
```